# Writing Ajax with jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to learn ajax. I have just aware of that some people write ajax with javascript but some people use jQuery. Which one is more useful? jQuery requires shortest code but why people use javascript?

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (in the past, but still present) is that we have like a zillion browsers and browser versions out there (mobile ones included).

If you want to be pretty comfortable that your ajax request works in all of those things, you typically grab some third-party library which abstracts all the known bugs/issues away and offers you a tiny interface.

That is pretty much the only reason why you want to use a library like jQuery.

Of course you can try to create your own cross-browser ajax code. If you have time to waste or you want to figure all the quirks this is probably a good thing. Otherwise, you would just re-invent the wheel for the 22 time.

Comment: you are so right for million browser thing! It is a little bit hard for me to understand javascript. jQuery looks easier. But as you said I have cross-browser problem. For example my code does not work with opera but works in other major browser. I've asked this question to learn javascript is a good solution for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery provides a simpler and cross-browser syntax for ajax calls. Some people don't want to rely on third party libraries (for security reasons), so they prefer to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

First, jQuery is a JavaScript library, so even if you are using jQuery you are still using JavaScript.

Now to answer your question, I bet there may be tones of reasons why not to use a library to make an Ajax request, but I guess that a common reason is that most libraries provide tones of features for everything from Ajax-request to DOM-manipulation and so forth. If you only want to make an Ajax-request and you won't be using the other features of a library, it might feel like a waste to load an entire library.

Answer (score 0):

ppl use pure javascript, if they not need other jquery advantages, or care about code size, or other reasons, why you would to use C if you can just program on assembler ?

Comment: because your time efficacy drops dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript library. It is JavaScript, it is just written by other people.

The Ajax functions it provides save development time.

On the other hand, it adds extra baggage you may not need.

Other libraries are available. Examples include [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/) and the various tiny libraries listed at [MicroJS](http://microjs.com/#).

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of reasons to using plain javascript. In example:

- There are restrictions of using jquery, defined by the system or some person who are responsible for that rule
- Some people don't know Jquery or cannot deal with it.
- And so far...

Answer (score 0):

Really it depends of what you're making.

jQuery it's pretty useful because it can reduce the work hours you need to accomplish a task, but it's not capable of everything.

So, it boils to what you need, if you only need ajax functionalities and you have time, you could write a custom cross browser function to do so, but if you don't care about including jQuery in your page (extra request) or you really need it for a lot of things, it's a really nice solution.

Both are javascript, but jQuery it's written and tested by a lot of people

Comment: Actually I need other jquery functions. And my major problem is browser compatibility. I can not still run my ajax code on Opera. If you think using jquery prevents browser compatibility, I will give up to use jquery for ajax.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax is somewhat simple. You need a server side file (`php` or `asp`) to process ajax request and to return result.

The usual procedure is something like;

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

You can read about jQuery AJAX Methods [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp).

***[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)*** is the official jQuery ajax documentation.

Comment: Thanks! but I have already know how can I call an ajax function. I just want to learn what other people think. Thanks for your comment.